# whois lookup shows correct ip but why my browser can not find IP address of domain?

Tags: web, dns

My website suddenly stopped working.

When I search for the domain name in WHOIS websites it is showing the correct server ip address and correct DNS IP address.

I can reach the website by its IP address but somehow when I am trying the domain name in browser its not working and its showing "This site can’t be reached"!

There is no error in my server log.
I tried different browsers and different systems and it is same issue.

I am really confused. Even when I am sending `GET` requests with *Postman* to my domain, it not reachable but sending request to IP is working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in appear that the problem was DNS on our local system. we changed it to 8.8.8.8 and then we could access to our domain!

Answer (score 2):

whois and DNS resolution are two separate things and one does not imply anything for the other, so in short, except in very specific cases, if you have a DNS resolution problem you should use DNS troubleshooting tools, not the whois and especially not web-based whois (the only relevant whois is the registry one).

Now you are giving so few details that noone can really help.

Among the possible ideas to check and probable problems:

- you forgot to renew the domain, your registrar put it on hold or worse deleted it (that you can see in whois)
- you did a change in the DNS resolution and now it does not work anymore, use online troubleshooting tools like Zonemaster or DNSViz; alternatively your registrar and/or webhosting company should be able to help (since you are neither giving here the domain name nor details about the troubleshooting you do: for DNS problems, the browser is not the first tool to use, look instead at `dig`).

Answer (score 0):

it's usually because you use an addon domain, not the main domain for hosting orders that are set up on cpanel whm